# "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'." in Popover class name

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
<Popover.Group  className="hidden space-x-10 md:flex" as="nav">
```

I get an error at `className`:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Comment: What is the type of the props of `Popover.Group`? It looks like it must be some kind of generic or mapped type, since that error only occurs in unusual situations. (The error you'd get if it just didn't have a `className` prop would be "Property 'className' does not exist on type ____".) We can't help you figure out how to solve the real underlying problem without more information.

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue (and only your issue) when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  If people can easily see the issue for themselves, they can more easily diagnose and/or fix it.  Good luck!